# Cast object to generic

Tags: swift, generics

I am creating a function to be used in different occasions. But for this, I need to Cast the return of a function to the Object that I pass as generic in this main function.

```
func makeRequestToApi<T>(object: T, url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { request in
        if let json = request.result.value {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                let data = JSON(json)
                let object: [T] = self.createProductObject(data) as Any as! [T]

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.delegate?.networkingDidUpdate(object)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that I only need to call this way:

`networkingController.makeRequestToApi(Product, url: Urls.menu)`

This function will return an array of products `self.createProductObject(data) -> [Product]`

But Xcode make me add `.self` to the first parameter in makeRequestToApi

`networkingController.makeRequestToApi(Product.self, url: Urls.menu)`

This way, as I see, Swift will not convert the return of my class to Product as I need it.

Anyone knows what I need to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
func makeRequestToApi<T>(create: JSON -> [T], url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { request in
        if let json = request.result.value {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                let data = JSON(json)
                let object = create(data)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.delegate?.networkingDidUpdate(object)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

makeRequestToApi(createProductObject, url: Urls.menu)
```

EDIT: This compiles for me (you probably have to adjust your delegate method):

```
import Foundation

struct Product {}

protocol Delegate : class {
    func networkingDidUpdate<T>(obj: [T])
}

class Test {
    weak var delegate : Delegate?

    func makeRequestToApi<T>(create: JSON -> [T], url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { request in
            guard let json = request.result.value else { return }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {

                let object = create(JSON(json))

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.delegate?.networkingDidUpdate(object)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func createProductObject(json: JSON) -> [Product] {
        return [Product()]
    }
}


let test = Test()
test.makeRequestToApi(test.createProductObject, url: "")
```